# 1-1 User Chat APIs with Admin access (for mobile and web) (PHP/JS)

Tags: web-apps, javascript, php, api, chat

I need to have a 1-1 chat application for a website/app with the following functionality.

Certain classes of users can chat with other classes of users

Admins should be able to view chats, but not delete them

Chats can only be deleted if both parties want to delete a chat

If there's any Chat solution which meets these requirements I would be grateful for a recommendation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is ConnectyCube chat provider, they give three levels of access: owner, admin and user. On client-side you can manage the relations of the users and their level of access. Their documentation:
https://developers.connectycube.com/server/chat?id=chat-dialog-model
https://developers.connectycube.com/js